# checked column in datagrid telerik

Tags: datagrid, telerik

I have a problem with checkbox in telerik datagrid,
I want to check the checkbox based on other field's value `

```
enter columns: [


        //define template column with checkbox and attach click event handler
        {
          title: 'Active', 
          headerTemplate: `<input type="checkbox" id="header-chb" class="k-checkbox">
<label class="k-checkbox-label" for="header-chb"> Active </label>`,

          template: 

          function(dataItem){
          <?php
          $lof = 1; // I want this value based on XOK Field
          if($lof==0){$sd = "checked";} else { $sd ="";}?>
          return `
          <input type="checkbox" id="${dataItem.TestNum}" class="k-checkbox" <?php echo $sd ?>>
<label class="k-checkbox-label" for="${dataItem.TestNum}"></label>`},width: 380,
          locked: true
        },
         {
          field:"XOK",
          width: 20,
          title: "TestCode"
        },
```

How can I check the checkbox if XOK value is 1 and leave unchecked if the value is 0. If possible I want to hide/remove XOK column. Any Help will be apreciated, Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Ive just found the answer by removing php and replaced by
var semuanya = dataItem.XOK;